# Feed sb sth VS feed sb on sth

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Sentences:

> I feed the dog biscuits.
>
> I feed the dog **on** biscuits.

Does **feed on** mean **to give as a regular food,** and **feed** mean simply **to give food**?

Explain.

Thank you.

Comment: Please look up *feed on* in a couple of dictionaries, and note how it's normally used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

> I feed the dog biscuits.

Means that you give the dog some amount of biscuits. Since biscuits are typically not a primary food source, it may mean that you feed the dog a snack or a treat. On its own, this sentence implies a single event, not something that continues or is regular.

> I feed the dog on biscuits.

Means that the dog's primary food source is biscuits- that the dog is fed biscuits much of the time and may not receive any other food at all.